# I'm trying to communicate between Android, PHP and Arduino through HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, post

I am a C++ lover, but my university assignment requires me to code Android (Java), web (PHP) and Arduino, and I have no experience in Java.

I have at least tried for Android code, but it says it won't compile, and I don't get why. I get bunch of "class, interface, or enum expected" errors and I simply can't find it over anywhere,

(Oh, and please ignore Korean, I go to Korean university, and my professor wants me to include Korean in my program).

```
package ---my package---;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;
import static android.graphics.Color.RED;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mp3_1, mp3_2, mp3_3, mp3_4, finishbutton;
    TextView wakeornot;
    char datatosend;
    String datareceived;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        wakeornot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wakeornot);
        mp3_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mp3_1);
        mp3_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mp3_2);
        mp3_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mp3_3);
        mp3_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mp3_4);
        finishbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishbutton);

        mp3_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1번 자장가를 재생합니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                datatosend = '1';

                HttpPostData();
            }});

        mp3_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2번 자장가를 재생합니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                datatosend = '2';

                HttpPostData();
            }});

        mp3_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3번 자장가를 재생합니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                datatosend = '3';

                HttpPostData();
            }});

        mp3_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4번 자장가를 재생합니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                datatosend = '4';

                HttpPostData();
            }});

        finishbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "프로그램을 종료합니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }});
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void HttpPostData() {
        try {
            //URL 설정 및 접속
            URL url = new URL("https://---domain---.net");
            HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //전송 모드 설정
            http.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
            http.setDoInput(true);                         // 서버에서 읽기 모드 지정
            http.setDoOutput(true);                        // 서버로 쓰기 모드 지정
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");                 // 전송 방식은 POST

            http.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //서버로 값 전송
            StringBuffer buffer;
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("datatosend").append("=").append(datatosend);

            OutputStreamWriter outStream = new OutputStreamWriter(http.getOutputStream(), "EUC-KR");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream);
            writer.write(buffer.toString());
            writer.flush();

            //서버에서 전송 받기
            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "EUC-KR");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str;
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {       // 서버에서 라인단위로 보내줄 것이므로 라인단위로 읽는다
                builder.append(str).append("\n");                     // View에 표시하기 위해 라인 구분자 추가
            }
            datareceived = builder.toString();                  // 전송결과를 전역 변수에 저장

            if (datareceived.equals("5")) {
                datareceived = "! 깨어 !";
                ((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.wakeornot))).setText(datareceived);
                ((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.wakeornot))).setTextColor(RED);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "아기의 상태에 변화가 있습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if (datareceived.equals("6")) {
                datareceived = "자고";
                ((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.wakeornot))).setText(datareceived);
                ((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.wakeornot))).setTextColor(GREEN);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "아기의 상태에 변화가 있습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        } // try
    }
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get bunch of "class, interface, or enum expected" errors and I
>   simply can't find it over anywhere

1. You have an extra bracket before below code. Remove it.

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```
2. Shouldn't your package name is `package my package;` ?